# Adding a variable into an Object path in Angular 5 HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an object on firebase that within it has a series of objects for each user on a particular document. The Object initial Object key for each user is their UID. I am trying to check whether the user has an object. The issue is that passing in the `userId` dynamically does not find the correct path:

```
this.userId = this._auth.currentUserId;

<p *ngIf="tenancy_offer.application.members.userId">UserId exists</p>
```

This returns null as it is looking for a key of `userId` rather than the users actual ID. So, how do I pass in a variable dynamically as part of an object path?

This is the Object in firestore: 
[image]

Comment: the `tenancy_offer.application.members` is array of users?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Nope, it is a dictionary. I have just uploaded a picture for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `userId` is hash (like `onq9wawO7...`) in mebers objetc then try

```
<p *ngIf="tenancy_offer.application.members[userId]">UserId exists</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the index

```
<p *ngIf="tenancy_offer.application.members[0]">UserId exists</p>
```